# How do I take input using the gets module when using Frank and cucumber?

Tags: ios, ruby, cucumber, frank

### Background Info

I am currently using [Frank with Cucumber](http://www.testingwithfrank.com/) to automate testing on an iOS app.
Everything works as it should, I can Frankify the app, run it, etc. Symbiote works as it should, as does Cucumber. I've already written many testing steps that work exactly as I intended. All my steps are written in Ruby.

### Problem

My problem is that, as everything works as it should, I want the ability to have a step that takes input. I was thinking I could just use the gets module, but for some reason it doesn't wait for any user input and I only see the prompt works after the feature fails.
Here's the code for that step:

```
    When(/^I verify the device via text$/) do
  print "What's the Verify link?"
  link_to_app = gets.chomp
  sleep 20
  press_home_on_simulator
  sleep 1
  # for this next part you're gonna need this link:
  # https://github.com/moredip/Frank/issues/177
  # It's used to go out of the app and open an html doc in safari
  html_format = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title></title><meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL='#{link_to_app}'\"></head><boßdy></body></html>"
  html = html_format
  require 'tempfile'
  file = Tempfile.new(['launch', '.html'])

  begin
    file.write(html)
    %x( /usr/bin/open "#{file.path}" -a "iPhone Simulator" )
  ensure
    file.close
    file.unlink
  end

  sleep 2
end
```

This basically is meant to take a link that can only be taken from a SMS text and allow me to automatically go to that link in the simulator (this is used for account verification in the app).
As I said before, instead of the prompt stopping and waiting for any input, it simply skips past.

### Question

Basically, how can I, while using Frank and Cucumber, make the gets module work and take input for me?

Thank you

Comment: Not all the test cases can be automatized...

Answer (score 0):

Try using STDIN.gets, rather than plain old gets